# Why did matplotlib stop working on Fedora?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fedora

I'm trying to use matplotlib on Fedora, but constantly get messages like

```
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

even with the MWE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
fig = plt.figure();
```

For more complex scripts it throws segmentation faults. On Ubuntu everything works fine.
Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I receive the same error when using matplotlib on Fedora, but it still works fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2])
plt.show()
```

/usr/bin/python /home/djohnson/R/Working/foo.py
[djohnson@julian Working]$ /usr/bin/python /home/djohnson/R/Working/foo.py
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()

[output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZPDM.png)

Did you run plt.show()?

Comment: plt.show() does not change anything and sure it still plots normally. But as I said, try more complex plots like this small example: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/features.html#sphx-glr-gallery-features-py I get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning that is telling you the code is trying to plot something using Matplotlib's QT backend. There are more such backends and some of them are interactive and some are not. Please refer to Matplotlib's documentation on various backends.

In non-interactive backends like your linux terminal, the function imshow **still needs show()** at the end. **Jupyter notebook cells are calling show() by default every time**, please check this explanation from the source code.

```
# This function's signature is rewritten upon backend-load by switch_backend.
def show(*args, **kwargs):
"""
Display all open figures.

Parameters
----------
block : bool, optional
    Whether to wait for all figures to be closed before returning.

    If `True` block and run the GUI main loop until all figure windows
    are closed.

    If `False` ensure that all figure windows are displayed and return
    immediately.  In this case, you are responsible for ensuring
    that the event loop is running to have responsive figures.

    Defaults to True in non-interactive mode and to False in interactive
    mode (see `.pyplot.isinteractive`).

See Also
--------
ion : Enable interactive mode, which shows / updates the figure after
      every plotting command, so that calling ``show()`` is not necessary.
ioff : Disable interactive mode.
savefig : Save the figure to an image file instead of showing it on screen.

Notes
-----
**Saving figures to file and showing a window at the same time**

If you want an image file as well as a user interface window, use
`.pyplot.savefig` before `.pyplot.show`. At the end of (a blocking)
``show()`` the figure is closed and thus unregistered from pyplot. Calling
`.pyplot.savefig` afterwards would save a new and thus empty figure. This
limitation of command order does not apply if the show is non-blocking or
if you keep a reference to the figure and use `.Figure.savefig`.

**Auto-show in jupyter notebooks**

The jupyter backends (activated via ``%matplotlib inline``,
``%matplotlib notebook``, or ``%matplotlib widget``), call ``show()`` at
the end of every cell by default. Thus, you usually don't have to call it
explicitly there.
"""
```